# create a dictionary from two other dictionaries with similarity between them

Tags: python, dictionary

I got two dictionary like this :

```
dict1= {'MO': ['N-2', 'N-8', 'N-7', 'N-6', 'N-9'], 'MO2': ['N0-6'], 'MO3': ['N-2']}
dict2= {'N-2': ['NUMBER1'], 'N0-6': ['NUMBER16'], 'N-9': ['NUMBER33']
```

I would like to create a dictionary like this

```
dict3={'MO'['NUMBER1','NUMBER33'], 'MO2':['NUMBER16']}
```

So I developed this code but when I add the values, it is not working

```
for ki, vi in dict2.items():
    for key, value in (itertools.chain.from_iterable([itertools.product((k, ), v) for k, v in dict3.items()])):
        if (ki == v):
            print vi
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A one-liner. :D

```
{k: [y for x in xs if x in d2 for y in d2[x]] for k, xs in d1.items()}
```

1. We loop through each key (`k`) and value (`xs`) in `d1`.
2. For each item `x` in `xs`, we find a path through `d2` if `d2` contains `x`.
3. We flatten the resulting lists using `y ... for y in d2[x]`.

Here's another way to format it that might be easier to understand:

```
{
    k: [
        y
        for x in xs if x in d2
        for y in d2[x]
    ]
    for k, xs in d1.items()
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You only need to loop over one of the dictionaries:

```
dict1= {'MO': ['N-2', 'N-8', 'N-7', 'N-6', 'N-9'], 'MO2': ['N0-6'], 'MO3': ['N-2']}
dict2= {'N-2': ['NUMBER1'], 'N0-6': ['NUMBER16'], 'N-9': ['NUMBER33']}
dict3 = {}
for key, subkeys in dict1.items():
    for subkey in subkeys:
        dict3.setdefault(key, []).extend(dict2.get(subkey, []))
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this using defatuldict

```
from collections import defaultdict
d =defaultdict(list)
for k in dict1.keys():
    for value in dict1[k]:
        temp = dict2.get(value)
        if temp:
            d[k].append(temp)
```

Output

```
defaultdict(list,
            {'MO': [['NUMBER1'], ['NUMBER33']],
             'MO2': [['NUMBER16']],
             'MO3': [['NUMBER1']]})
```